# Check Chromium loading

Tags: chromium

I use chrome in kiosk mode, opened by my c++ script.

What i want to do is to check when chromium is done to load the pages.

There are any way?

Comment: is the page that chromium opens local or on the web?

Comment: Where is the question specific to Raspberry Pi?